# Google Sheets Run Library

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, lib

I got a problems to run a library on google sheet.

this is my library. Actually I'm not sure if it is, I just typed out my code and deploy it as a library only. Is this considered a library?
https://script.google.com/d/1caK6rW1--NmMSzSq0DHT0d4J-ucIdPv7KDPOmo16mZ9LBEZJo1OxXm8K/edit?usp=sharing

```
/**
 * Finds a combination of numbers that add up to a specific value.
 *
 * @param {A1:A16} data The range of cells containing the data.
 * @param {B1} target The target value.
 * @return An array containing the combination of values that add up to the target value.
 * @customfunction
 */
function findCombination(data, target) {
  var values = data;
  var n = values.length;
  var found = false;
  var result = [];
  
  for (var i = 1; i < Math.pow(2, n); i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      if ((i & (1 << j)) !== 0) {
        sum += values[j][0];
      }
    }
    
    if (sum === target) {
      result = values.map(function(value, index) {
        if ((i & (1 << index)) !== 0) {
          return value[0];
        } else {
          return "";
        }
      });
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if (!found) {
    result = ["No combination found"];
  }
  
  return result;
}
```

And then is this my code on google sheets,

```
function run(data, target) {

  Mylibrary.findCombination(data, target)

}
```

But when I type the run function in google sheet, it doesn't work very well. No error is being reported either, I don't understand how to improve it.

The purpose of this is to integrate all my scattered code into one library, and then other sheets call the lib for easy maintenance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Google Apps Script project including `run(data, target)` correctly installs your script as a library, unfortunately, `run(data, target)` is not returned from `Mylibrary.findCombination(data, target)`, because of no `return`. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. If my understanding is correct, please modify your showing script as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function run(data, target) {
  return Mylibrary.findCombination(data, target);
}
```

#### Reference

- [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)